# Regarding 32-bit microcontrollers, is TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers the only available option?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on a ML project that includes ARM-based microcontrollers such as Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense. I did some research but could not find any alternative for these microcontrollers rather than TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers (TFLM).

Hence I am curious if there are available options that is on par with TFLM.